# how to set custom order of headers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that I have pivotted and looks like this. Basically, this just shows the number of item count per day.

```
MY OUTPUT
date        item1   item4   item6
12/12/17    10      1       13
12/13/18    22      5       32
12/14/19    9       3       22
```

but the final output requested from me is to show all the items, even if there were results for that day or not, it should show on the table.

```
EXPECTED OUTPUT
date        item1   item2   item3   item4   item5   item6
12/12/17    10                      1               13
12/13/18    22                      5               32
12/14/19    9                       3               22
```

is there a way with pandas to allow me to predefine the headers? which will then match to my actual results?

what I tried doing was to create a separate mysql table, then query and transform to dataframe that table which basically contains the list of items and the sequence. And then I left merged the item list with the actual data. Now I have a table with the actual data and the item list. But when I try to pivot, only the columns with values are seen in the pivot.

```
SAMPLE SOURCE DATA
item    date        serial_no
item1   12/12/17    001
item1   12/12/17    002
item4   12/13/17    003
item6   12/14/17    004
item4   12/13/17    005
item6   12/14/17    006
item1   12/12/17    007
item1   12/14/17    008

and how I pivot is by:
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(
    index = ['date'], 
    values = [serial_no], 
    columns = ['items'], 
    aggfunc = [len]
)
```

Comment: Can you share the data you pivoted to get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is using `reindex` -

```
df = df.set_index('date')

i = int(re.search('\d+', df.columns[0]).group(0)) 
j = int(re.search('\d+', df.columns[-1]).group(0))    

df.reindex(columns=['item{}'.format(i) for i in range(i, j + 1)], fill_value='')

          item1 item2 item3  item4 item5  item6
date                                           
12/12/17     10                  1           13
12/13/18     22                  5           32
12/14/19      9                  3           22
```

Although it may be possible to do this during the pivot step itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [41]: n = pd.to_numeric(df.columns.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False), errors='coerce')

In [42]: idx = 'item' + pd.Series(np.arange(n.min(), n.max()+1).astype(int)).astype(str)

In [43]: df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('item')] \
           .join(df.filter(regex='^item') \
           .reindex(idx, axis=1))
Out[43]:
       date  item1  item2  item3  item4  item5  item6
0  12/12/17     10    NaN    NaN      1    NaN     13
1  12/13/18     22    NaN    NaN      5    NaN     32
2  12/14/19      9    NaN    NaN      3    NaN     22
```

NOTE: it might be easier to manipulate your data **before** pivoting to have the same result